# Is it acceptable to rewrite the sentence in 'it-cleft'?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it acceptable to rewrite the folowing sentence in 'it-cleft'?

> 1. The workers haven't had a holiday for ages.
> 2. It is for ages that the workers haven't had a holiday.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't write it as you did in number 2. If you want to write the sentence with "it", then I would adjust it to something like this:

> It has been ages since the workers have had a holiday.

Comment: It's OK, but that isn't a cleft, since it since it does not contain a relative clause.